# Google Map not displaying in PHP/MySQL Page

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a PHP page that displays MySQL data in a infowindow on a Google Map.  The page displayed fine last time I checked it but now will not draw the map.  Can someone point me in the right direction as to what is broken?

Here is the URL:  http://tinyurl.com/8jy78xq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the width and height issue, try this css

```
#map {
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
   border: none;
}
```